# my inverse index is very slow any suggestions?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a text file where each line has a bunch of text. (in the actual file there are no line numbers) like this:

```
line#:     text:
0          This is some text
1          More text
2          whats for lunch
```

I want a function that returns a dictionary mapping each word to its line number occurrence essentially designing an inverseindex.

i.e. `{'This':{1}, 'text':{0,1}, 'for':{2} ... }`

After scanning the text file, (this takes .18 seconds) I put the lines into a list of lists, such that each position in the list stores the split line. i.e.:

`[['This', 'is', 'some', 'text'], ['More', ...] ...]`

After which I use `enumerate()` to extract the position and create the dictionary. I have a solution already but its so ugly and it took me so long that I want to see another more elegant solution.

For reference my algorithm runs for 882.28 seconds i.e. 15 minutes on 1099 lines and 753210 words. In other words decidedly non pythonic.

```
def invidx(strlist):
    # return algoritm execution time
    start = time.time()  

    f = open(strlist, 'r')
    wordLoc = []
    for line in f:    
        s = line.split()
        wordLoc.append(list(s)) 
    f.close()

    # benchmark
    print 'job completed in %.2fs' % (time.time() - start) 

    try:
        q = {}
        for a, b in enumerate(wordLoc):
            l = set()
            for w in b :
                if w not in q:
                    l = {a for a, b in enumerate(wordLoc) if w in b}
                    q[w] = l
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Interrupt detected: aborting...'
        print 'Failed to complete indexing, ran for %.2fs' % \
            (time.time() - start)
        exit(0)                  

    return q
```

*EDIT:*

as per request code is above. Go easy on me guys.

Comment: Posting code is not suggested, it's mandatory.  How are we going to help you optimize an algorithm we can't read?

Comment: This would be more appropriate on code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Assuming, of course you actually post your code ;)

Comment: thanks guys. posted above. Sometimes you just have a funny feeling your code is bad...this is one of those times.

Comment: I can see the need for code if the objective is to tweak and polish the existing code. However, in this case the code is so slow that a complete change, such as different algorithm or, as suggested in the answers, using built-in features, is likely to be needed. Neither answer builds on the existing code.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Read strilanc's answer ... posting the code is critical to understanding why it acts badly, which is a lot more important than just having someone throw code at the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the line numbers using `enumerate` when you scan the file initially, and add line numbers to the dict of `set`s as you go.

myfile.txt:

```
a b c
b x y
a c b
```

index it:

```
index = {}
with open('myfile.txt') as F:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(F):
        for word in line.split():
            index.setdefault(word, set()).add(line_num)

index
=> {'a': set([0, 2]),
 'b': set([0, 1, 2]),
 'c': set([0, 2]),
 'x': set([1]),
 'y': set([1])}
```

Comment: setdefault is really useful

Answer (score 2):

The line responsible for the slowdown is this one:

```
l = {a for a, b in enumerate(wordLoc) if w in b}
```

Every time you find a word you haven't seen yet, you re-enumerate every single line and see if contains the word. This is going to contribute O(NumberOfUniqueWords * NumberOfLines) operations overall, which is quadratic-ish in the size of the input.

You're already enumerating every word of every line. Why not just add them up as you go?

```
for w in b :
    if w not in q: q[w] = []
    q[w].append(a)
```

This should take O(NumberOfWords) time, which is linear in the size of the input instead of quadratic (ish). You touch each thing once, instead of once per unique word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(set)
with open('abc') as f:
   for i,line in enumerate(f): #enumerate returns the line number as well as the line
       words = line.split()    #splt the line using str.split()
       for word in words:      #iterate over words and add to it's corresponding set
           dic[word.lower()].add(i)
print dic
```

**output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'set'>,
{'whats': set([2]),
 'for': set([2]),
 'this': set([0]),
 'text': set([0, 1]),
 'is': set([0]),
 'some': set([0]),
 'lunch': set([2]),
 'more': set([1])})
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work and I'm fairly sure it's faster than your version:

```
from time import time

def invidx(strlist):
    # return algoritm execution time
    start = time()

    wordLocs = []
    unique_words = set()
    with open(strlist, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            unique_words.update(words)
            wordLocs.append(set(words))

    # benchmark
    print 'job completed in %.2fs' % (time() - start)

    try:
        q = {}
        for unique_word in unique_words:
            occurrences = set()
            for line, words in enumerate(wordLocs):
                if unique_word in words:
                    occurrences.add(line)
            q[unique_word] = occurrences

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ('Interrupt detected: aborting...\n'
              ('Failed to complete indexing, ran for %.2fs' % (time() - start)))
        exit(0)

    return q

from pprint import pprint
pprint(invidx('strlist.txt'))
```

Output from your trivial test file:

```
job completed in 0.00s
{'More': set([1]),
 'This': set([0]),
 'for': set([2]),
 'is': set([0]),
 'lunch': set([2]),
 'some': set([0]),
 'text': set([0, 1]),
 'whats': set([2])}
```